# Greenrobot Eventbus holds variables

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I have problem with Eventbus with following symptoms. I have activity which starts another activity. There is used Eventbus and boolean value set. This value is changed during activity run. For first run is all ok, but in second run, I got bad value changed in previous run. Here is code:

public class ListArchiveTabs extends FragmentActivity {

```
private boolean isStartFragment = true;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isStartFragment = true;
    EventBus.getDefault().registerSticky(this);
    System.out.println("Create archive activity " + isStartFragment);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    System.out.println("Destroy archive activity");
}

public void onEventMainThread(GetArchiveEvent event)
{
    if(isStartFragment == true) {
        isStartFragment = false;
    } else {
    }
}
```

}

In first run is isStartFragment true, but other runs shows false.

Comment: You might want to show what `isStartFragment` is and where/how it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onEventMainThread` the method you have it running in the main thread, the first time you run it no any event, when it happens again, to be executed in the same thread, is executing sequentially why the flag is changed to false, change the event to an execution on a thread or change the logic of the flag
remember that a `sticky` is an ongoing event and register it that way, look if there is an event of this kind, and to be then directly calls his `onEvent` therefore executed sequentially and the flag is changed

Comment: Yes, but it not help.

Comment: In System.out.println - first run of activity is true correctly, but if I change it to false in activity, destroy activity and create it again, I got false.

Comment: could show the full code of the activity where you have the problem

Comment: because it uses registerSticky?

Comment: you have a onEvent amending the flag?